# package play.libs.ws does not exist in play 2.6.x project

Tags: java, playframework

I have added `ws` dependency in `build.sbt` in the project but while compiling I am getting package `play.libs.ws` does not exist.

Below are the screenshots of `build.sbt`, Controller and error message on compile command of sbt.

**build.sbt**

```
name := """tools-server"""
organization := "com.example"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies += guice

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ws
)
```

**my Controller**

```
package controllers;

import play.libs.ws.WSClient;
import play.mvc.*;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;


public class HomeController extends Controller {

    private final WSClient ws;

    @Inject
    HomeController(WSClient ws) {
        this.ws = ws;
    }

    public CompletionStage<Result> index(String url) {
        CompletionStage<? extends Integer> respPromise = this.sendHttpRequest(url);

        return respPromise.thenApply(resp -> ok(resp.toString()));
    }


    private CompletionStage<? extends Integer> sendHttpRequest(String url) {
        return this.ws.url(url).setRequestTimeout(Duration.of(10000, ChronoUnit.MILLIS)).get().thenApply(resp -> resp.getStatus());
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting while compiling sbt.

```
play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[package play.libs.ws does not exist]
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:34)
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:34)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1(PlayReload.scala:33)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:28)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:24)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.$anonfun$compile$3(PlayReload.scala:51)
        at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
```

Comment: Please provide actual code in the question instead of a screenshot of your code.

Comment: @Paxz I have added the code in the description.